# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Serialization of 'Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element' is not allowed'

Tags: checkout, fatal-error, exception, ce-1.9.2.2

I was trying to build a custom payment extension for magento. I noticed when I click "Place Order", I got this error from network tab. I tried testing with all cache disabled and enabled. Also I'm not using Mage_Core_Model_Config::getNode() anywhere. The exact error is -

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Serialization of 'Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element' is not allowed' in [no active file] on line 0`

any help please! I searched other questions related to this problem but nothing works for me.